# index.js:1 Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `index`. Index is unique

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to assign index to key of dynamic list component but it gives warning of duplicate keys. Here is the code below

```
function App() {
  const [userInput, setUserInput] = useState('');

  let calcLengthHandler = (event)=>{
    setUserInput(event.target.value);
  }

  let charArr = [...userInput.split('')];
  let charCmp = ( <div>
        {
          charArr.map((character,index)=>{
            return (
              <CharComponent onClick={deleteCharCmp} char={character} key='index'></CharComponent>
            )
          })
        }
    </div>)

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className='container'>
        <h1 className='container-output'>Dynamic List</h1>
        <input type='text' className='user-input' onChange={calcLengthHandler} value={userInput} placeholder='Enter user input'></input>
        <p className='container-output inline'>Length of user input: {userInput.length}</p>
        <ValidationComponent length={userInput.length}></ValidationComponent>
        {charCmp}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Every time a user enters some string, I am trying to create a component with each character. I have further functionality to achieve which I have not included. 
On adding debugger just before .map function, I see its called twice which may be causing the issue. I guess 1. when the component is initialized and 2. when I call {charCmp}. How can I resolve duplicate keys problem here?

Comment: the index you wrote is inside a quote , replace `key='index'` with `key={index}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sets the `key` attribute to the string `'index'`:

```
key='index'
```

This sets the `key` attribute to the value of the `index` variable:

```
key={index}
```